# Not able to connect to MySQL; All User, Privileges checked so many times

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL on linux box. Able to connect locally using root. Not able to connect using MySQL client on my laptop. I tried creating many users; made user all privileges are ok..

Did lots of Google.. Still no help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was configuration in my.cnf file

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

So by default mysql is configured to connect only locally. We need to comment this line to allow mysql to connect from another laptop. After this still we need all Privileges etc. this is added level of security.

Comment: Please be cautious about this. It is typically bad practice to have MySQL listen on any address other than local. For development and testing it's fine but I wouldn't advise on it on a production machine.

Comment: I agree Gerard.. For testing/development we can comment out the line. For production you should instead put IP address of all app servers which need to connect to this mysql server

Comment: We restrict IP address on AWS Security Groups.. Its easy to maintain there; rather than cnf file..